# Replace default catalog search API

Tags: product, catalogsearch

I have an external catalog search API and want to replace the default catalog search API of Magento 2 with it.
I am new to Magento. Can you tell me the best ways to do this? Any guides or tutorials are appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have to do that using REST API. Hope that will help you. Please follow `https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/rest/search-endpoint.html`.

Comment: Hi @viru. Do you mean to replace the `V1/search` endpoint with my external API endpoint? I want to replace the existing catalog search function of Magento with my APIs. Not using it. Thank you.

Comment: You have to use this after replacement but need more customization. you need to read REST API using Magento swagger and get more ideas about that.